# Integrating $\sin^2(x)/x^2$ - understanding different arguments

Tags: complex-analysis

I know this is an old problem and it has been answered some times, but I dont understand some reasoning that is applied in some solutions: 
I read a few times that in the following problem the last two integrals can be ignored as they do not surround any poles, with the contours as displayed in the sketch.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{4}\left( \int_{C0+C2} \frac{e^{i2z}}{z^2}dz+\int_{C0+C1} \frac{e^{-2iz}}{z^2}dz-\int_{C0+C1} \frac{2}{z^2}dz\right)$$

[image]

To me this argumentation appears weird as the second term does contribute with the semicircle around the origin.

How I would go about it is as follows: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}-2}{z^2}dz = -\frac{1}{4}\left(P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2iz}}{z^2} dz+ P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-2iz}}{z^2}dz-P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2}{z^2}dz\right)$$

The last term is clearly zero as known from the theorems of higher order than 1. The former two terms however need to be integrated over a different curve $C1/C2$ such that the term is surpressed as $R\rightarrow \infty$. As the first term doesnt include any pole (C0+C2) and semiloops over the pole counter-clockwise

$$P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2iz}}{z^2} dz = 2\pi$$

The second term however includes the pole (C0+C1) and hence evaluates to
$$P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-2iz}}{z^2} dz = -2\pi - 4\pi$$

Leading to the right solution of $\pi$.

But yes, I am still left with the argumentation of the others that I would like to understand. Anyone?

Comment: With the contours as sketched, the first integral contributes $0$ since the contour $C_0 + C_2$ doesn't enclose the pole, and the third integral contributes $0$ since $\operatorname{Res}(2/z^2; 0) = 0$. Thus only the second integral remains, with a contribution of $-\frac{1}{4}(-2\pi i)(-2i) = \pi$. I suspect people actually were considering a contour with a small semicircle around $0$ in the _lower_ half-plane.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What somehow leaves me concerned is that why can we leave the Principal Value completely out of the discussion and hence also the half-circles? That would also contribute in the first integral (what I did above in the second part)?

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer since it does not use complex analysis and contour integration.*

The antiderivative is rather simple to establish $$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} dx =\text{Si}(2 x)-\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x}$$ which leads to $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} dx =\pi$$